# Zombiejs not installing

Tags: node.js, npm, zombie.js, nvm

I've followed the instructions at zombie.js.org to install it ( specifically npm install zombie --save-dev ).  I also have installed io.js a requirement of zombie.  However when I check it's there by running a file consisting of

```
const Browser = require(zombie);
```

I get an error stating

```
ReferenceError: zombie is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/martin/zombie/1.js:1:87)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

Ive used also used npm to make sure it's the correct version of node/iojs.  I'm a linux newbie so I may be overlooking something obvious.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `require("zombie");` put `"zombie"` in quotes

Comment: Wow I feel stupid now!  I copied and pasted it into terminal the used echo 'require('zombie')' >> 1.js when it pasted it removed the speech marks.  Thanks.